# ¿Cómo puedo consultar dos tablas y mostrar resultado de una sola?

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo una base de datos muy sencilla para una red social. El detalle es que me he quedado trabado en una cosa.
Tengo estas dos tablas

```
         ->TABLA AMIGOS<-
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|
|  id  | id_usuario1 | id_usuario2|
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|
|   1  |      1      |       2    |
|   2  |      3      |       4    |
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|

       ->TABLA SOLICITUDES<-
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|
|  id  |   id_envia  |  id_recibe |
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|
|   4  |      3      |       15   |
|   5  |      3      |       1    |
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|
```

Supongamos que el usuario ***id: 1*** quiere enviarle una solicitud al usuario ***id: 3***, pero tal usuario ya le ha enviado una solicitud anteriormente significa que no puede ser enviada, por lo que intento que la base de datos me mande una tabla así:

```
                      ->TABLA COMPROBACION<-
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|
|  id  |   id_envia  |  id_recibe | id_usuario1 | id_usuario2 |
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|
|   5  |      3      |       1    |     null    |      null   |
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|
```

O si el usuario ***id: 4*** quiere enviarle una solicitud al usuario ***id: 3***, la tabla mostaría algo así:

```
                      ->TABLA COMPROBACION<-
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|
|  id  |   id_envia  |  id_recibe | id_usuario1 | id_usuario2 |
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|
|   5  |     null    |    null    |      3      |      4      |
|++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|+++++++++++++|
```

Esto lo hago tanto para las solicitudes como para cuando se muestra un perfil, darle información al usuario que ya tienen una relación entre ambos.

Actualmente estuve trabajando con una consulta que me hacía lo que pedía, pero lo estuve probando con muy pocos datos en la base de datos, para ser exactos solo con 2 usuarios. Cuando intenté hacer la prueba con más usuarios, la tabla me mostraba resultados que no eran los deseados.

La consulta es esta:

```
SELECT solicitudes.id_envia, solicitudes.id_recibe, ami.id_usuario1, ami.id_usuario2
FROM solicitudes
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE id_usuario1 = 1 AND id_usuario2 = 3 OR id_usuario1 = 3 AND id_usuario2 = 1
    ) AS ami ON ami.id_usuario1  = 1 OR ami.id_usuario2 = 1
WHERE solicitudes.id_envia= 1 AND solicitudes.id_recibe= 3
    OR solicitudes.id_envia= 3 AND solicitudes.id_recibe= 1
            
UNION

SELECT solicitudes.id_envia, solicitudes.id_recibe, ami.id_usuario1, ami.id_usuario2 
FROM solicitudes
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE id_usuario1 = 1 AND id_usuario2 = 3 OR id_usuario1 = 3 AND id_usuario2 = 1
    ) AS ami ON ami.id_usuario1 = 1 OR ami.id_usuario2 = 1
WHERE ami.id_usuario1 = 1 AND ami.id_usuario2 = 3
    OR ami.id_usuario1 = 3 AND ami.id_usuario2 = 1;
```

He intentado un montón de consultas similares, pero nunca me termina saliendo como debería.

Comment: No entiendo porque buscas esas tablas de salida, cuando lo que tenes que validar es que el usuario "destino" no le haya enviado una solicitud al usuario "origen"... con una simple query...

Comment: Lo que trato es que si usuario **A** busca el perfil del usuario **B**, en su perfil aparezca algo como ***Solicitud enviada***, ***Aceptar solicitud*** o ***Amigos***, por eso tal consulta. En el servidor simplemente verifico que campo se encuentra vacío para dar una respuesta como esa, también en caso que el usuario intente modificar el código del cliente e intente ejecutar la función que envía la solicitud poder realizar la misma consulta para que sea imposible tener dos registros iguales en ambas tablas y que no aparezca el mismo usuario en las solicitudes y tu lista de amigos.

Comment: Pero esa logica de negocios, sale de un query simple... no? no tenes que armar una tabla como lo que estas pensando, porque estas tratando de poner en un query, una regla de negocios, que ya tenes en tus tablas...